# switch graphics with checkboxInput

Tags: r, shiny

Consider the toy example below. I am trying to display a different graphic when the checkbox is = TRUE but appears to have no effect. I am using 'switch' to display the graphics based on its label. Thanks for any hints on how to display an alternate graphic with a conditional statement(if).

```
   library(shiny)

    mytest <- c("first","second")
   # Define UI for application that draws a histogram
    ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),

        sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
          selectInput(inputId = "test",
                      label = "Test",
                      choices = mytest,
                      selected = "first"),
          checkboxInput("checkbox","check this box",FALSE)),

        mainPanel(
           plotOutput("distPlot")
        )))

      server <- function(input, output) {

    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
      switch(input$test,
             "first" = plot(rnorm(100)),
             
             if("checkbox" == FALSE){
             "second" = plot(rnorm(1000),col="blue")
             } else{
       #I want the graphic below to be displayed when the checkbox = TRUE or checked
            "second" = plot(rnorm(10000),col='red')   
             }
      )
})
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need the value of the checkbox you have to reference it using `input[["checkbox]]` or `input$checkbox`.

I assume you wanted a black coloured block when the dropdown is "first" and a blue/red one (depending on the checkbox) when the dropdown is "second"?

The solution disables the check box when the first item is selected. To do that you can use the functions `enabled`/`disabled` from the shinyjs package. For that we have to initialise shinyjs in the ui.

```r
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)

mytest <- c("first","second")
# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(
  useShinyjs(), # to initialise shinyjs
  
  # Application title
  titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      selectInput(inputId = "test",
                  label = "Test",
                  choices = mytest,
                  selected = "first"),
      disabled( # start as disabled
        checkboxInput("checkbox","check this box", FALSE))
      ),
    
    mainPanel(
      plotOutput("distPlot")
    )))


server <- function(input, output) {
  
  output$distPlot <- renderPlot({
    switch(
      input$test,
      "first" = { 
        plot(rnorm(100))
        disable("checkbox")
      },
      {
        enable("checkbox")
        if(input[["checkbox"]] == FALSE){
         "second" = plot(rnorm(1000), col="blue")
        } else{
         "second" = plot(rnorm(10000), col="red")   
        }
      }
    )
  })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: @Jan-- That works perfectly fine for the second graph. Is there a way to hide or disable the checkbox when I select the first graph (first option on dropdown)?

Comment: The two most common ways that come to my mind: use the [shinyjs package to enable/disable](https://rdrr.io/cran/shinyjs/man/disabled.html) it. Or use a [`conditionalPanel`](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/latest/conditionalPanel.html) to hide/show it. Think you can handle it? I can show how it works but you have to pick then.

Comment: I think the first option looks appropriate for what I am trying to do. Also, I am running the code you suggested works really well when using `plot(rnorm(1000))` but when I replace it with a long ggplot graphic, shiny does not display the graphic. I wonder why. Could it be that I need to put the long ggplot statement in a string?

Comment: Figured out that I needed to 'print' ggplot statement for the graphic to show. If you can show me with a small example how to hide or disable the check box when is not used I would really appreciate it.

Comment: I added it to the solution above.